# Backpropagation using only numpy

Tags: machine-learning, numpy, backpropagation, implementation

I've been trying to implement the backpropagation algorithm using only numpy, I've already done the Keras version, but when implementing the numpy version, the loss is diverging as seen in the image below:

[image]

I initialized the weights using the glorot initialization (Keras default), used SGD with the same learning rate as in Keras, using sigmoid as activation function, but still, the algorithm can't converge for a simple XOR.

I think there is something wrong with the backward pass but I can't figure out what it is.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


class MLP:
    @staticmethod
    def glorot_initializer(fan_in, fan_out):
        factor = 4 * np.sqrt(6 / (fan_in + fan_out))
        return np.random.uniform(-factor, factor, (fan_in, fan_out))

    @staticmethod
    def relu(x):
        return np.maximum(x, 0)

    @staticmethod
    def step(x):
        return np.heaviside(x, 1)

    @staticmethod
    def sigmoid(x):
        return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))

    @staticmethod
    def sigmoid_diff(x):
        sig = MLP.sigmoid(x)
        return sig * (1 - sig)

    def __init__(self, input_size, output_size, hidden_layers, hidden_size):
        self.input_size = input_size
        self.output_size = output_size
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.layers = list()
        self.grads = list()

        # input layer
        W = self.glorot_initializer(input_size, hidden_size)
        b = np.zeros((hidden_size, 1))
        self.layers.append(dict(W=W, b=b, type='input'))

        # hidden layers
        for i in range(hidden_layers):
            W = self.glorot_initializer(hidden_size, hidden_size)
            b = np.zeros((hidden_size, 1))
            layer = dict(W=W, b=b, type='hidden')
            self.layers.append(layer)

        # output layer
        W = self.glorot_initializer(hidden_size, output_size)
        b = np.zeros((output_size, 1))
        self.layers.append(dict(W=W, b=b, type='output'))

    def forward_pass(self, x):
        for layer in self.layers:
            x = np.dot(x, layer['W']) + layer['b'].T
            layer['output'] = x
            x = self.sigmoid(x)
            layer['activation_output'] = x
        return x

    def backward_pass(self, x, y, forward_pass):
        m = y.shape[0]
        dlda = 2*(y - forward_pass)  # considering MSE
        dlda = np.sum(dlda, axis=0, keepdims=True) / m
        self.grads = list()

        for i in range(len(self.layers)-1, -1, -1):
            grad = dict()

            z = self.layers[i]['output']
            dadz = np.sum(self.sigmoid_diff(z), axis=0, keepdims=True) / m
            if self.layers[i]['type'] == 'input':
                dzdw = np.sum(x, axis=0, keepdims=True) / m
            else:
                dzdw = np.sum(self.layers[i-1]['activation_output'], axis=0, keepdims=True) / m

            grad['b'] = dlda.dot(dadz).T
            grad['W'] = dlda.dot(dadz).T.dot(dzdw).T
            dzda_prev = self.layers[i]['W'].T
            dlda = np.sum(dlda.dot(dadz).dot(dzda_prev), axis=1, keepdims=True)

            self.grads.append(grad)

        self.grads.reverse()
        return self.grads

    def update_parameters(self, lr=0.2):
        for layer, grad in zip(self.layers, self.grads):
            layer['W'] -= lr * grad['W']
            layer['b'] -= lr * grad['b']


if __name__ == '__main__':
    epochs = 20000
    input = np.array([[0, 0], [1, 1], [0, 1], [1, 0]])
    target = np.array([[0.0], [0.0], [1.0], [1.0]])

    input_size = input.shape[1]
    output_size = target.shape[1]
    mlp = MLP(input_size=input_size, output_size=output_size, hidden_layers=2, hidden_size=2)

    loss = np.zeros(epochs)

    for i in range(epochs):
        fp = mlp.forward_pass(input)
        bp = mlp.backward_pass(input, target, fp)
        mlp.update_parameters(lr=.01)
        loss[i] = np.sum((fp-target)**2/fp.shape[0])

    plt.plot(target)
    plt.plot(fp)
    plt.show()

    plt.plot(loss)
    plt.title('LOSS x EPOCHS')
    plt.show()
```

Any help, would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Lucas, it would be nice if you refer to some guys repository who implemented it.. like I did it for MNIST..